# Having issues trying to fix this control flow problem

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements, variable-assignment

I've thought I figured out how basic javascript logic  works, but here I must have forgot something.

```js
 let firstElementSavedIndex = 1
 console.log(firstElementSavedIndex)
 firstElementSavedIndex = 0;
 console.log(firstElementSavedIndex)
 if (firstElementSavedIndex !== undefined || firstElementSavedIndex !== 0) firstElementSavedIndex -= 1;
                  
                    
 console.log(firstElementSavedIndex)
```

The code  I created above I wanted to use as a guard to prevent firstElementSavedIndex from decrementing unless firstElementSavedIndex isn't undefined or 0.

However the code above decrements even if firstElementSavedIndex is 0.

I must be missing something basic, but I havent found any solutions so far.

Any help would be appreciated.

-Hendrik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the if block the expression becomes

```
0 !== undefined || 0 !== 0
true || 0 !== 0
true
```

Since you are using `or` as long something evaluates to `true` the whole expression will become `true` hence the code goes inside the if block.

To fix this you need to replace `||` with `&&` and make the conditional as `savedIndex greater than 0`.

```js
let firstElementSavedIndex = 1;
console.log(firstElementSavedIndex);
 
firstElementSavedIndex = 0;
console.log(firstElementSavedIndex);

if (firstElementSavedIndex !== undefined && firstElementSavedIndex > 0) {
    firstElementSavedIndex -= 1;
}
console.log(firstElementSavedIndex);
```

now it becomes

```
0 !== undefined && 0 > 0
true && 0 > 0
true && false
false
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed something so simple, thanks for the help. This fixed my problem.